# wxPython custom SplashScreen with progress gauge

Tags: python, wxpython, progress-bar, wxwidgets, splash-screen

How do I create a custom splash screen in wxPython that has a loading bar and begins automatically on startup?

My answer with a code sample is below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd been trying to create a custom splash screen that incorporated a progress gauge (loading bar) using wxPython that loaded automatically on start up. After some tweaking, I was finally able to create one. In order to do this, I had to override the application's MainLoop() method. Below is the Application module I used.

```
class Application(wx.App):
"""Inherits from wx.App and serves as the entry point for the wxPython application. 
To run the program, an instance of this class is created and its method "MainLoop" is called.
"""

    def __init__(self):
        """Initializes our wx.App by calling its super method. It also instantiates a new 
        ApplicationManager which manages the different components of the project session.
        """
        wx.App.__init__(self, redirect = False)  


    def OnInit(self):
        """Instantiates the main frame. The OnInit method is only available for classes that derive 
        wx.App. Override this method to do application initialization.
        """
        self.appManager = ApplicationManager()
        self.appManager.applicationFrame = ApplicationFrame(self)
        self.appManager.splashScreen = SplashScreenDialog()
        self.keepRunning = True
        return True


    def MainLoop(self):
        """This function is overridden to allow the splash screen to load properly at the start 
        of the application. On the first loop, the method displays the splash screen and loads 
        the necessary files. When the application is closed, the keepRunning variable is set 
        to false (see ApplicationFrame) and the while loop is ended.
        """
        self.loadedSplashScreen = False

        # Create an event loop and make it active. If you are only going to temporarily have a nested 
        # event loop then you should get a reference to the old one and set it as the active event 
        # loop when you are done with this one...
        eventLoop = wx.GUIEventLoop()
        oldEventLoop = wx.EventLoop.GetActive()
        wx.EventLoop.SetActive(eventLoop)

        # This outer loop determines when to exit the application, for this example we let the main 
        # frame reset this flag when it closes.
        while self.keepRunning:
            # At this point in the outer loop you could do whatever you implemented your own MainLoop 
            # for. It should be quick and non-blocking, otherwise your GUI will freeze.  

            # Place splash screen events on the stack
            if (not self.loadedSplashScreen):
                self.appManager.splashScreen.Show(True)

            # This inner loop will process any GUI events until there are no more waiting.
            while eventLoop.Pending():
                eventLoop.Dispatch()

            if (not self.loadedSplashScreen):
                for i in range(0,10000000):
                    # Do loading stuff here
                    j = float(i/100000.0)
                    self.appManager.splashScreen.gauge.SetValue(j)

                self.appManager.splashScreen.Close()
                self.appManager.applicationFrame.Show(True)
                self.SetTopWindow(self.appManager.applicationFrame)
                self.loadedSplashScreen = True

            # Send idle events to idle handlers. This may need to be throttle back so 
            # there is not too much CPU time spent in the idle handlers.
            time.sleep(0.10) # Throttling back
            eventLoop.ProcessIdle()

        wx.EventLoop.SetActive(oldEventLoop)
```

When you close the application, you need to set self.keepRunning to false in order for the MainLoop() method to finish. Hope this helps!

Comment: @Xilpex I no longer have access to the full code. I think you should be able to figure it out from the code above though. Sorry!